# Make SQL Server Compact Edition database case sensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm writing an application that uses a SQL Server CE database into which I write data from a `.csv` file.

The column I have to use for the primary key is an alphanumeric string where the only way to distinguish two keys can be the case of a single character.

Example:

```
Key1: Ac001
Key2: ac001
```

While I've read that the database can be configured to be case sensitive, and I haven't found a way to do it.

Another problem I have is, that I can only edit the database in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2008

If it is not possible to to there, what tools would I need and how do I do it? I suppose I could import an externally created database into my project

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835498(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: See a great tool here: https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2008/07/working-with-case-sensitive-sql-compact.html 
@DavidBrabant - the question is about SQL Server Compact, not SQL Server